# angular 9.07 run without debugging

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I have an application that I have been working on for some time. But since today `ng build` does not produce a runnable code!!

The same application in debug mode run like always

PS

```
C:\AskLily\back_office> ng build
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
ES5 bundle generation complete.
chunk {polyfills} polyfills-es2015.js, polyfills-es2015.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]     
chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 752 kB [initial] [rendered]   
chunk {firebase-auth} firebase-auth-es2015.js, firebase-auth-es2015.js.map (firebase-auth) 181 kB  [rendered]
chunk {firebase-auth} firebase-auth-es5.js, firebase-auth-es5.js.map (firebase-auth) 293 kB  [rendered]    
chunk {styles} styles-es2015.js, styles-es2015.js.map (styles) 180 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles-es5.js, styles-es5.js.map (styles) 183 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {login-login-module} login-login-module-es2015.js, login-login-module-es2015.js.map (login-login-module) 20.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {login-login-module} login-login-module-es5.js, login-login-module-es5.js.map (login-login-module) 22.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor-es2015.js, vendor-es2015.js.map (vendor) 9.28 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor-es5.js, vendor-es5.js.map (vendor) 10.9 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main-es2015.js, main-es2015.js.map (main) 401 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main-es5.js, main-es5.js.map (main) 479 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es2015.js, runtime-es2015.js.map (runtime) 9.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es5.js, runtime-es5.js.map (runtime) 9.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 129 kB [entry] [rendered]
Date: 2021-03-06T19:21:19.336Z - Hash: 84ab1434a3a9af537bce - Time: 19095ms
```

Looks good but does not execute. When running from visual studio code, it actually stops and you have to close it in order to continue.

The same behaviour when I load it to my AWS S3 bucket: nothing happens.
I clean and recompiled all and still - debug work but without debugging halts.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while at it!) - Also, read our [ask] page and come back to [edit] your question to improve it.  Good questions tend to solicit quick, high-quality responses from the community

Comment: Question: how are you running the application? the command above only builds it